# the counter of for of loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, for-of-loop

I am studying javascript, and learning for loop. I am sure it's basic part but I can't get how the counter variable works..

I am making the battle application, and this is the function that is executed when user clicks the battle log, then it will show the last log and the index of it in console.log.

The battle log in the function is the array that stores nested arrays of users input.

```
let lastLoggedEntry;


function printLogHandler() {

  let i = 0;

  for (const logEntry of battleLog) {
    if ((!lastLoggedEntry && lastLoggedEntry !== 0) || lastLoggedEntry < i) {
      console.log(`#${i}`);
      for (const key in logEntry) {
        console.log(`${key} => ${logEntry[key]}`);
      }
      lastLoggedEntry = i;
      break;
    }

    i++;
  }
}
```

My question is the initial valuable is set in outside of the for loop(i = 0). but when the user clicks the battle log again, and this function executes again, how for loops has been saving the data of last i and logEntry's value? ( second time when user clisks, it will be i = 1, and logEntry = 0 already)

Also, how can it skip "let i = 0" from second time? because its not only for loop, it executes the function, I thought javascript reads let i = 0 again and it will reset to 0. ( it won't of course but I want to understand why)

Hopefully, you guys could help me out. Thank you,

Comment: Your code saves `i` in a global variable, which is checked the next time the function is called.

Comment: Hi, yes I understand first i is global scope. and when first time, the variable of global scope will assign to i in local scope. I get it but why from second time the function is executed, does not global scope assign to local scope one, and can local scope keep own variable from last time?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. There is missing closure in the sample provided. There should be another closing bracket for the code to validate.
2. `lastLoggedEntry` must be defined as a variable before it is used.
3. It is not clear what the contents of `battleLog` are.

I think if you clarify these things it may be easier to answer your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for letting me know. I modified my question, so hopefully it makes you easier to understand. Thank you for your help:)